# How to set PDF copyright metadata using ColdFusion (&iText)

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, itext

I'm attempting to set the copyright metadata of a PDF using ColdFusion & iText.  Adobe ColdFusion 9-11 allow getting & setting the Title, Subject, Keywords, Creator & Author fields, but doesn't appear to allow access to the "Additional Metadata" properties. (This is my first SO question.)

I found a potential iTextSharp/C# solution and have tried to convert it to CFML, but I haven't been able to determine how to successfully access System.IO.MemoryStream() w/ColdFusion. I get a "Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface MemoryStream. Ensure that the name is correct and that the component or interface exists." error and searching the internet doesn't offer any results.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6942531/693068

NOTE: I'm using iText because the PDF files are created using ABBYY FineReader. I've encountered numerous issues in the past where ColdFusion refuses to identify non-Acrobat-generated PDFs as valid PDFs when using isPDFFile().

Any ideas?  Does the functionality currently exist and just not documented anywhere?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Too long for comments ...)

As Ryan mentioned, it might be possible using DDX. The `cfpdf` documentation lists `Metadata` as a supported element. So you may want to look into that option first.

> I found a potential iTextSharp/C# solution

That said, there is no need to use an external C# library. CF is already bundled with an older version of iText (written in java). So use the java classes instead. iTextSharp is a port of the original java library, so the class and method names will usually be the same.

```
source = "c:/path/to/input.pdf";
target = "c:/path/to/output.pdf";
reader = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader").init( source );
output = createObject("java", "java.io.FileOutputStream").init( target );
stamper = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper").init( reader, output );

copyrightName = "YOUR NAME HERE";
copyrightUrl = "http://www.example.com/";

baos = createObject("java", "java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream").init();
xmp = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.xml.xmp.XmpWriter").init(baos);
xmp.addRdfDescription("xmlns:dc=""http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/""", "<dc:rights><rdf:Alt><rdf:li xml:lang=""x-default"">"& copyrightName &"</rdf:li></rdf:Alt></dc:rights>");
xmp.addRdfDescription("xmlns:xmpRights=""http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/rights/"""
                        , "<xmpRights:Marked>True</xmpRights:Marked><xmpRights:WebStatement>"& copyrightUrl &"</xmpRights:WebStatement>");
xmp.close();
stamper.setXmpMetadata(baos.toByteArray());
stamper.close();
```

Comment: This works!  (Using iText is much easier than using the DDX method.) I was trying to determine what MemoryStream() was, how it related to the script and if there was a CF/Java alternative.  It looks like it wasn't even necessary.  I was also using "itextpdf" instead of "lowagie". Updating these additional metadata fields doesn't appear to work if "itextpdf" is used. Thanks!

Comment: iText underwent a [significant license change a few years back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IText#History). ColdFusion is bundled with one of the older versions, which are denoted by the package "com.lowagie.*". The newer versions ie 5.x use "com.itextpdf.*". Since CF does not use the newer version, that is why it does not work.

Comment: *looks like it wasn't even necessary* No, it is required. It is used to store the xmp metadata before it is added to the pdf. In the example above I used a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do this with the DDX capabilities.  See these links:

- [Using DDX to unlock the potential of PDF manipulation in ColdFusion](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/ddx_pdf.html)
- [`<cfpdf>` documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7995.html)

`System.IO.MemoryStream` is a C# class. You won't be able to access it from CFML directly.  You could try to use the [.net integration features](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec13e1a-7ffd.html) to access it, or the iTextSharp solution, directly.

Comment: Regarding the article, the "DDX Language Elements section" is "404 Not Found". http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/es/sdkHelp/programmer/sdkHelp/ddxRefMain.150.1.html

Comment: In the CFML reference link, there's a reference to "ColdFusion 11 restricted DDX elements", but that page requires login. After logging in, a "Not Permitted" message is displayed.
https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/pages/editpage.action?pageId=87505187#cfpdf-RestrictedDDXelements

Comment: @JamesMoberg - Look in the [regular docs](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfpdf). Not sure where you got that last link. It's for *modifying* the wiki, which I doubt you are authorized for, which explains the permissions error. I have not used it, but the cfpdf docs say the `Metadata` element is supported. See also [(PDF) - Assembler Service and DDX Reference - Adobe Systems](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/ddxRef.pdf)

Comment: Thanks. Regarding "copyright status", the PDF has a link to the XMP Specification, but it returns a 404. http://www.adobe.com/products/xmp/index.html The correct link is http://www.adobe.com/products/xmp/ (This occurs way too often. Adobe should monitor their log files for errors & fix broken links.)

Comment: *Adobe should monitor their log files for errors & fix broken links* Amen.